# Baking lights onto base color for LOTS of objects in a scene

Tags: rendering, baking, lighting

I have a scene that I'm going to be building that will have several trees, rocks, and palms. I'm building the scene for AR and want to optimize the scene by baking the lights onto the diffuse so I don't have to use any real-time lights when it's loaded. My only problem is that the trees have several hundred leaves each, baking a light for each leaf and switching the image node to the baked diffuse would be unrealistically time-consuming. Is there any way that I can bake lights quickly and without having to manually switch out the diffuse after bake?
I'm thinking of maybe creating a separate UV map that includes all the leaves on one UV island, but, I don't know how to approach this potential solution. Select all "leaf" meshes, Unwrap, and pack?